# Trying to put IntergerMath on Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, average, distance, turtle-graphics

Since I'm done with making this code of the Average and the Distance:

```
x1=eval(input("Please insert a first number: "))
y1=eval(input("Please insert a second number: "))
x2=eval(input("Please insert a third number: "))
y2=eval(input("Please insert a fourth number: "))
add = x1
add = add + y1
add = add + x2
add = add + y2
average = add/4
d= distanceFormula(x1,y1,x2,y2)
print("Average:", average)
print("Distance:", d)
```

I am now currently working on adding graphics to connect intergermath on a bar graph with python turtle graphics. However, I came across upon with some problems when I'm typing this code (Input):

```
def doBar(height, clr):
   begin_fill()
   color(clr)
   setheading(90)
   forward(height)
   right(90)
   forward(40)
   right(90)
   end_fill()

y_values = [str(y1), str(y2)]
x_values = [str(x1), str(x2)]
colors= ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
up()
goto(-300, -200)
down()
idx = 0
for value in y_values:
    doBar(value, colors[idx])
    idx += 1
```

And here's the result on the output that I got some errors after it went out as normal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 in main
 doBar(value, colors[idx])
 in doBar
 forward(height)
 line 1637, in forward
 self._go(distance)
 line 1604, in _go
 ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
 line 257, in __mul__
 return Vec2D(self[0]*other, self[1]*other)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

So am I trying to do here is using both average and distance as an input and the output should be asking a user to insert four numbers and it will draw four bars on a python turtle graphics.

So how can I make this code work on graphics?

Comment: Please don't ever use `eval(input())`. It's dangerous.

Comment: How dangerous is eval(input())?

Comment: [Very!](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) Arbitrary malicious code will be executed, for instance in the way shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/5067311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height` is being passed into `doBar()` as a *string*. The function then passes the string to the `forward()` function, however, that requires either an integer or a float.

The y values are converted to strings here:

```
y_values = [str(y1), str(y2)]
```

You can fix it by removing the `str()` conversion:

```
y_values = [y1, y2]
```

---

`doBar()` draws a triangle, not a rectangle. It needs one more vertical line of length `height` to be drawn for the right hand side of the rectangle:

```
def doBar(height, clr):
    begin_fill()
    color(clr)
    setheading(90)
    forward(height)
    right(90)
    forward(40)
    right(90)
    forward(height)    # draw back down to the x-axis
    end_fill()
```

Comment: All right new problem: Despite that you did helped me solving that problem of yours, I got a result that it only drew two triangles but not bars as I originally thought.

Comment: @AntonO.Obyedkov: look at your `doBar()` function. It draws a line up `height`, then draws a line of length 40 to the right, then stops and fills. There are only 2 lines so that makes a triangle. You need to add another call to `forward(height)` before filling to draw the right side of the bar.

Comment: One problem, one problem to go: How can I make the appearance of four color bars as an output?

Comment: @AntonO.Obyedkov: you need to draw more bars. Try `for value in y_values*2:`